# jQuery UI touch events working on IPad / iPhone / iPod?

Tags: iphone, ipad, jquery-ui, webkit

I was working on a protoype using jquery UI resizabel plugin, but I noticed that it doesnt work on the iPad.

Might it be a problem with the touch/click event?

I worked previously with a sliders plugin and they were pretty good on that device so I beleive it is do-able and I wonder how can fix the resizable pluing to make it work on the iPAd too..

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would help to show us a bit of your code. Somebody may know an alternative method of accomplishing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found myself this

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/

Answer (score 2):

Another option is http://touchpunch.furf.com/

> jQuery UI Touch Punch is a small hack that enables the use of touch events on sites using the jQuery UI user interface library.