# jQuery UI for touchscreen devices

Tags: jquery

I am disappointed to find that jQuery UI is pretty useless when it comes to touch screen devices such as the Samsung Galaxy and the iPhone.

Are there any alternate libraries specifically designed with touch screen devices in mind? Maybe even with an iOS graphics set?

Or can jQuery be augmented so as to work with these devices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI touch events working on IPad / iPhone / iPod?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158190/jquery-ui-touch-events-working-on-ipad-iphone-ipod)

Comment: jQuery UI Touch Punch is a small hack that enables the use of touch events on sites using the jQuery UI user interface library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, In fact it can! Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808663/jquery-ui-slider-touch-support-on-mobile).

Drop this into an existing jQuery UI project:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Touch punch was made to offer touch functionality to jQuery UI.

Comment: Excellent! Was worried I'd have to we-write a lot of stuff :)